# Invalid redirect_uri issue

Tags: identity-server, horizon

I installed Sitecore 9.3 on Azure. Everything is working fine. Next I installed Sitecore Horizon 9.3 on Azure. Then If I try to click on Horizon icon from Sitecore. It is giving error.

I tried below one to resolve but no luck.

1. Added entry to "Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml" file under section  "AllowedCorsOrigins" with "https://sitecore-9-3-v6-rg-383150-ah.azurewebsites.net" and restarted the app. Still the result is same.
2. Checked file Sitecore.IdentityServer.AuthoringHost.xml on server, that has entry of corsorgin with "https://sitecore-9-3-v6-rg-383150-ah.azurewebsites.net" url.

[image]

Sitecore Identity Logs

[image]

Comment: Is /signin-oidc added in IS config files for allowed redirect Uri's ?

Comment: Is this still an issue? @Venkat did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but there was no answer. I had this same issue and here's how I resolved it. In your Identity Website's `\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` file, be sure your `<AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>` hostname *exactly* matches the actual hostname you're using! This is sensitive to `http://` and `https://`! So if you're trying to go to, **http**://mysite/sitecore but your `<AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>` is **https**://mysite/sitecore you'll see this error. You probably just need to force HTTPS via a redirect in that case. Hope this helps!